# PHPMailer signed mail -> empty body + no signed

Tags: php, phpmailer, sign

I'm trying to send a signed mail using PHPMailer, but there is no way.

First of all, the code and the Debug output:

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 4;
$mail->Host = 'MyServer.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'Myusername';
$mail->Password = 'Mypassword';
$mail->SMTPSecure = '';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->setFrom('Boss@mail.com', 'boss');
$mail->Subject = 'Subject';

$mail->addAddress("mymail@test.net", 'test user');

$mail->Body = 'Lorem ipsum dolore......';

$mail->AltBody = 'Lorem ipsum dolore......';

$mail->sign(
    'certs/ServerCertificate.cer', 
    'certs/PrivateKey.key', 
    '' //I tested with key and withouth (generated with openssl)
);

printf($mail->send());
```

> 2017-08-07 10:08:16   Connection: opening to @IP:587,
>   timeout=300, options=array (
>                                           ) 2017-08-07 10:08:16 Connection: opened 2017-08-07 10:08:16  SERVER -> CLIENT: 220
>   MXServer.net ESMTP Postfix 2017-08-07 10:08:16    CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: EHLO localhost 2017-08-07 10:08:16    SERVER -> CLIENT:
>   MXServer.net
>                                           250-PIPELINING
>                                           250-SIZE 20480000
>                                           250-VRFY
>                                           250-ETRN
>                                           250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN
>                                           250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN
>                                           250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
>                                           250-8BITMIME
>                                           250 DSN 2017-08-07 10:08:16   CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-08-07 10:08:16    SERVER ->
>   CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2017-08-07 10:08:16  CLIENT -> SERVER:
>   b3JkaW5hZG9yMjA= 2017-08-07 10:08:16  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334
>   UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2017-08-07 10:08:16  CLIENT -> SERVER: YmJzY29mYg==
>   2017-08-07 10:08:16   SERVER -> CLIENT: 235 2.0.0 Authentication
>   successful 2017-08-07 10:08:16    CLIENT -> SERVER: MAIL
>   FROM: 2017-08-07 10:08:16  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250
>   2.1.0 Ok 2017-08-07 10:08:16  CLIENT -> SERVER: RCPT TO: 2017-08-07 10:08:17   SERVER -> CLIENT: 250
>   2.1.5 Ok 2017-08-07 10:08:17  CLIENT -> SERVER: DATA 2017-08-07 10:08:17  SERVER -> CLIENT: 354 End data with .
>   2017-08-07 10:08:17   CLIENT -> SERVER: Date: Mon, 7 Aug 2017 10:08:16
>   +0000 2017-08-07 10:08:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: To: Colegiat  2017-08-07 10:08:17  CLIENT -> SERVER: From: COFB
>    2017-08-07 10:08:17   CLIENT -> SERVER: Subject:
>   =?UTF-8?Q?Confirmaci=C3=B3_?= 2017-08-07 10:08:17 CLIENT -> SERVER: Message-ID: 
>   2017-08-07 10:08:17   CLIENT -> SERVER: X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.23
>   (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) 2017-08-07 10:08:17  CLIENT ->
>   SERVER: 2017-08-07 10:08:17   CLIENT -> SERVER: . 2017-08-07
>   10:08:17  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2514A730014
>   2017-08-07 10:08:17   CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-08-07 10:08:17  SERVER
>   -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 Bye 2017-08-07 10:08:17  Connection: closed

I have tried everything, but when I add the certificates I get a blank and unsigned mail.

I generated the certs using this commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in exported-cert.pfx -nocerts -out cert.key
openssl pkcs12 -in exported-cert.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.crt
openssl pkcs12 -in exported-cert.pfx -cacerts -out certchain.pem
```

You know anything?

Comment: Take a look at how signing is done [in the PHPMailer test suite](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/test/phpmailerTest.php#L1681) for guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

https://www.thesslstore.com/ssltools/ssl-converter.php

I don't know why, but converting with this webpage and all works!!

Comment: What did you convert them to? Thanks